# Need help on set up Android App with WooCommerce Rest API

Tags: android, json, rest, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying to figure out how to develop an android app which get data via json from my woocommerce eshop. After reading many posts it is very fuzzy.

After trying to get products with postman client with a Get request https://www.my-store.com/wc-api/v3/products with and without my Client keys and I got an Error status 0.

I also don't understand what is meant as "pretty permalinks", I got the default ones on lastest woocommerce version.

I am getting very frustrated so any help would be great.

Excuse my english.